# How to get part of tag in Symfony Clawler

Tags: php, symfony

`$node` is item of `$nodes` array, from foreach loop.
`$node` contains something like this:

```
<tag class="troll">
    <otherTag> Troll's Hat </otherTag>
    Troll
<tag>
```

I want to use

```
$result = $node->filter(' tag.troll ??? ')->text();
```

to capture only "Troll" text without any other tags.

Should I first remove all childs of `<tag>` ? 
Or just maybe there is a good selector for `filter()` function ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Xpath Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) and [Filter Xpath Method](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_filterXPath) for complex queries.
For example, your query will look like `$crawler->filterXPath('//tag[@class="troll"]/text()[last()]')->text()`